# IDbSet with IEnumerable Linq where casting required?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I am using IDbSet for a result set and trying to construct the "IN" type clause using LinQ.
My code is as follows:

```
public IDbSet<User> Users { get; set; }

public IDbSet<User> GetUsers(params int[] IDs)
{
    return from u in Users
           where IDs.Contains(u.Id)
           select u;
}
```

The complier does not like the where it states:
    Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Linq.IQueryable' to 'System.Data.Entity.IDbSet'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

I have tried the usual casting and As(ing).  But I cannot seem to get the compiler to accept this.
Am I in error here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not return query results as `IDbSet<T>`.

> An `IDbSet` represents the **collection of all entities** in the context, or that can be queried from the database, of a given type. `DbSet` is a concrete implementation of `IDbSet`.
>
> *from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg679233%28v=vs.113%29.aspx)*

You're trying to get only subset of entities. That's what `IQueryable<T>`/`IEnuemerable<T>` are for. Change method declaration to return `IQueryable<User>`:

```
public IQueryable<User> GetUsers(params int[] IDs)
{
    return from u in Users
           where IDs.Contains(u.Id)
           select u;
}
```

Difference between `IQueryable<T>` and `IEnuemerable<T>` is that when you return `IEnumerable<T>` every next LINQ query set on that instance will be executed as LINQ to Object, so you're SQL will not be affected:

```
var items = GetUsers().Select(x => x.SomeColumnName);
```

This one would still bring all columns from `Users` table into memory and project them as LINQ to Objects query.

With method returning `IQueryable<T>` the same code would affect how generated SQL looks like: data from only one column would be fetched from DB.